# Listen to Gmail email received and upload to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-cloud-storage, gmail-api

I would like to listen for emails received from a certain address, and upon this event, upload the attachment to Google Cloud Storage. Is this possible?

Comment: any progress with this problem, Max888 ?

Comment: @Vladimir no sorry. From what I remember I abandoned the idea.